# Building Apache Spark SQL Core

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to build Apache Spark SQL Core (1.4.1) and I get the following stack trace. But if I build the whole Spark Project everything's going well and the building finishes successfully. Any ideas?

The stack trace

```
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala:258: value globPathIfNecessary is not a member of org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
[error]         SparkHadoopUtil.get.globPathIfNecessary(qualified)
[error]                             ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala:263: value map is not a member of Array[Nothing]
[error]           globbedPaths.map(_.toString), None, None, extraOptions.toMap)(sqlContext))
[error]                        ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/expressions/MonotonicallyIncreasingID.scala:22: object Nondeterministic is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions
[error] import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.{Nondeterministic, LeafExpression}
[error]        ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/expressions/MonotonicallyIncreasingID.scala:36: not found: type Nondeterministic
[error] private[sql] case class MonotonicallyIncreasingID() extends LeafExpression with Nondeterministic {
[error]                                                                                 ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/expressions/SparkPartitionID.scala:22: object Nondeterministic is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions
[error] import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.{Nondeterministic, LeafExpression}
[error]        ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/expressions/SparkPartitionID.scala:30: not found: type Nondeterministic
[error] private[sql] case object SparkPartitionID extends LeafExpression with Nondeterministic {
[error]                                                                       ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/ddl.scala:252: value globPathIfNecessary is not a member of org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
[error]             SparkHadoopUtil.get.globPathIfNecessary(qualifiedPattern).map(_.toString).toArray
[error]                                 ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/Dev/spark/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/ddl.scala:279: value globPathIfNecessary is not a member of org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
[error]             SparkHadoopUtil.get.globPathIfNecessary(qualifiedPattern).map(_.toString).toArray
[error]                                 ^
[error] 8 errors found
[debug] Compilation failed (CompilerInterface)
[error] Compile failed at Jul 21, 2015 5:57:38 AM [29.605s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.435s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 21 05:57:38 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/609M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-sql_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed. CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-sql_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: Compile failed via zinc server
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.zincCompile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:136)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:86)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:303)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's no globPathIfNecessary in [SparkHadoopUtil](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala) so it must be your own modification.  When you run the build from the top level, the Maven reactor has visibility to the whole project and can see your changes.  When you run the build from the subproject, Maven looks for everything from outside of the subproject in your local repo, so it can't see any modifications unless you've installed them.  So run your build again from the top level but do an `install` instead of a `package` to get your modifications installed into your local repo.  Once you do that, executing a build from sql/core should be able to resolve your changes successfully.